# A tough counting question: Specified order

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Assume that there are $3n$ people in the population. These people are ranked randomly and uniformly. ( that is, each permutation is equally probable) There is a competition and $m+1+k$ people among those $3n$ is competing. Among those $m+1+k$ people, the highest ranked $n$ people will win a prize. ( Of course, $m+k$$\geqslant$$n$)

There are 2 different categories of this $m+1+k$ people.

Category M: There are $m+1$ people in this category and it is known that each is better ranked than $s$$\in${0,1,...,$2n-m-1-k$} people among those who are not competing.

Category K: There are $k$ people in this category and it is known that each is lower ranked than $n$ people among those who are not competing. And, it is known that these $n$ people are different from $s$ people mentioned in Category M

**Question: What is the probability of winning a prize of a person in Category M for arbitrary $n,m,k,s$ ?**

If it is difficult to understand, as an example, assume $n=1,m=0,k=1,s=0$. That is there are $3$ people in the whole population and $2$ of them are competing. There is 1 person, call it Person A, in Category M and $1$ person, call it person B, in category K. The person in category K is known to be lower ranked than 1 person who is not competing, call it person C.

Then, it is known that person C is higher ranked than person B and we want to compute the probability of person A being better ranked than person B. Since there are 3 possible rankings (A-B-C,B-A-C,B-C-A) which conforms these info, and each ranking is equally probable, Probability of A winning the prize is $2/3$

Comment: Where does this come from? Just curious...

Comment: I, myself, actually ended up with this question while I have been working on a more general problem. I need this step to be done to be able to get to solve that problem.

Comment: Perhaps there is another way to solve your general problem? Look for "XY problem"...